# Perform task only after getting "XmlHttpRequest" response

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest

Hi all,

```
            var xhrDownloadImage = function (url, callback) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.open("GET", url, true);
            xhr.responseType = "blob";

            xhr.onerror = function(e){console.log("Error: " + e)};
            xhr.onabort = function(e){console.log("Abort: " + e)};

            xhr.onload = function () {

                console.log("onload");

                var result;

                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    // image as blob
                    result = xhr.response;
                } else {
                    result = null;
                }

                callback(result);
            };

            console.log(xhr.send());
        };
```

I am calling the above function in a for loop,each time after executing the function i need to perform another function, say "function a". I use the xhr.response as the input of "function a".

But since it is async, it doesnt wait for the response and continues executing the loop. So i couldn't get the out put correctly.

I tried changing the XMLHttpRequest to sync. But in that case i get the following error:

```
Uncaught InvalidAccessError: Failed to set the 'responseType' property on 'XMLHttpRequest': the response type can only be changed for asynchronous HTTP requests made from a document.
```

How can i keep the 'XMLHttpRequest' async and do "function a" exactly after getting the response each time?

Please help,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what the callback is for:

```
xhrDownloadImage(url,a); // <--- this is how you call function "a"
```

Alternatively, if you have more than one function that you need to run after the download:

```
xhrDownloadImage(url,function(result){
    a(result);
    b(result);
    some_other_function();
});
```